# Passwordless ssh connection from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

How can I create an ssh key from Windows and install it on a Linux host using OpenSSH to log in without a password for each connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### CREATE AND INSTALL SSH KEY

First of all, we need to create a new key in the Windows pc (where we start the connection) using:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Don't change the default path or remember where you saved the key, it will be used for the next command.
Press enter another two times to avoid using a passphrase (if you don't want it).

After that, if you haven't change the default path, the key will be created into `{USERPROFILE}\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`.

Now, you can usually use the command `ssh-copy-id` for installing the key on the remote host, but unfortunately this command is not available on Windows, so we have to install it using this command:

```
type $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh {REMOTE_HOST} "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

or if your key is not in the default path:

```
type {RSA_KEY_PATH} | ssh {REMOTE_HOST} "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

and replace the `{RSA_KEY_PATH}` with your RSA path.

Replace `{REMOTE_HOST}` with the remote host IP/Name (like pi@192.168.0.1), launch the command, insert the password if required, and the work is done!

### IMPORTANT!

---

#### SETTING UP `.ssh` FOLDER

If the `~/.ssh` folder is not existing in your remote host, you need to configure them, this is usually done by the command `ssh-copy-id`, but we can not access to this power from Windows!
You need to connect to the remote host in ssh and create the `.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` file for the first time:

```
ssh {REMOTE_HOST}
```

1. Create the `.ssh` directory:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
```

2. Set the right permissions:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

3. Create the `authorized_keys` file:

```
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

4. Set the right permissions:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

#### NOTE

The `authorized_keys` is not a folder, if you try to create it using `mkdir`, the SSH connection passwordless will not work, and if you debug the ssh on the host, you will notice an error/log similar to:

> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is not a key file.

---

**ADD YOUR SSH KEY ON YOUR AGENT**

Run those two lines on your Windows pc to add the created key on your cmd/powershell:

```
ssh-agent $SHELL
ssh-add
```

Comment: How do you troubleshoot when you follow these steps and when attempting ssh name@server, it still asks for the password?